# Nightwatch.js correct tests fails most the times

Tags: automated-tests, nightwatch.js

I have some test witch are correct but fails most the times and i don't know why this is happening. For example one of the test looks like this.

```
'Create organization' : function (browser) {
    browser
       .waitForElementPresent('li[ng-class="createOrganizationClass"]', 15000)
       .click('li[ng-class="createOrganizationClass"]')
}
```

That is just the beginning of the test but the rest does not matter. The question is that the element `li[ng-class="createOrganizationClass"]` is always present, but in some cases i get the `element is not present` error and my tests fails. Why is that happening and how can i avoid this? Also it is happening with another elements so my test fails for this reason most the time.

Here is my `nightwatch.json` file.

```
{
    "src_folders" : ["src/tests"],
    "output_folder" : "reports",
    "custom_commands_path" : "src/customCommands",
    "custom_assertions_path" : "",
    "page_objects_path" : "",
    "globals_path" : "",

    "selenium" : {
      "start_process" : false,
      "server_path" : "",
      "log_path" : "",
      "port" : 4444,
      "cli_args" : {
        "webdriver.chrome.driver" : "",
        "webdriver.gecko.driver" : "./geckodriver",
        "webdriver.edge.driver" : ""
      }
    },

    "test_settings" : {
      "default" : {
        "launch_url" : "http://localhost",
        "selenium_port"  : 4444,
        "selenium_host"  : "localhost",
        "silent": true,
        "screenshots" : {
          "enabled" : false,
          "path" : ""
        },
        "desiredCapabilities": {
          "browserName": "firefox",
          "unexpectedAlertBehaviour": "accept",
          "marionette" : true,
          "acceptInsecureCerts" : true,
          "abortOnAssertionFailure": false
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Some information on your setup would be useful

Comment: @Stratos Ion, the config file is added.

Comment: Did you try Chrome instead? Nightwatch, depending on the version, had troubles locating elements with firefox.

Comment: No i did not try chrome. But anyway the elements are located, just not every time.

Comment: It would help if we could access the page with the element you are referring to, otherwise I can't think how I can help you.